# how to avoid being asked "Enter passphrase for key " when I'm doing ssh operation on a remote host?

Tags: ssh, git

I'm ssh into a remote host (linux, fedora) and I want to do ssh operation(git with bitbucket) there. There is ssh-agent running on that machine,

```
$ ps -e|grep sh-agent
 2203 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
```

but when I want to git, it requires me to enter the passphrase

```
$ git pull
Enter passphrase for key '/user/wgong/home/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Note: if I operate on that machine locally, it won't ask me to enter the passphrase

Comment: I haven't used it but there's a command ssh-add that I think is used for that kind of thing

Answer (score 223):

### In my opinion the best way of using ssh

Before using Git add your key to **ssh-agent**

Start **ssh-agent** if not started:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

Add your **private key** using **ssh-add**

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_key  
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_key:  
Identity added: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_key   
(/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_key)
```

Check if the key is added (parameter is a lowercase L):

```
$ ssh-add -l  
2048 55:96:1a:b1:31:f6:f0:6f:d8:a7:49:1a:e5:4c:94:6f  
/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa_key (RSA)
```

Try to connect to your Git server:

```
$ ssh git.example.com
```

Now you can use Git without extra passphrase prompts.

### Other ways

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt

Comment: but I have used Git add your key to ssh-agent, then how to do? thanks

Comment: @lily Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me.

Comment: @Roman Your solution works for me within a same xterm session. But when I open a new xterm session, I have to do it again.
Also the file name for me is “~/.ssh/id_ras” rather than “~/.ssh/id_ras_key”.
Finally I have found another solution that works for multiple xterm sessions:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095054/ssh-key-still-asking-for-password-and-passphrase)
where a single command is needed:
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa &>/dev/null

Comment: How do I make this persistent? Simply put it into `.bashrc`?

Comment: Executed those commands on Windows 10 from Git Bash and it worked!

Comment: FYI, the `eval` is needed because it outputs commands that export environment variables like SSH_AUTH_SOCK that are needed. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351725/why-eval-the-output-of-ssh-agent/351727

Comment: not work for me, all commands were successfull, the output from `ssh git@github.com` was `Hi, <name>, you successfully authenticated, but GitHub doesn't provide shell access. Connection to github.com closed.` then I have tried `git fetch` but was asked about the passphrase again and again.

Comment: @Nikita https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: This one worked for me.

Answer (score 50):

If you already have `ssh-agent` running then you can add the key, and you'll have to enter the passphrase once, and once only for that session.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You don't say what OS you're using, but if it happens to be Linux & Gnome then the "Passwords and Keys" application (CLI name: `seahorse`) can manage these so they are unlocked when you log in (no passphrase required). Other Linux desktop environments have their own managers. I'm not sure what other OS do here.

Comment: life saver, how to make a shortcut to your answer...

Comment: Great answer, though it would be best if you said how to start the ssh-agent too.

Answer (score 39):

You can easily remove passphrase of your key by using the following command

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

On the first prompt, enter the file path (or press Enter to use the default)
Second prompt, enter the old passphrase
Next prompt, just press enter to unset the passphrase

Looks like this is the easiest way!

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way.  That'll teach me to follow Raspberry Pi 'how to' pages without thinking it through...

Answer (score 8):

On Mac, add `UseKeyChain` to `~/.ssh/config`

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

and add the following

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
```

Answer (score 6):

The main reason for passphrase asking is  that your key is encrypted, compare these two:

- not encrypted

  ```
  $ head ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----            
  AIIAogIBAAKCAQEAtOJQ0Z3ZbyzuknnHqn5oMCmNf8zGmERhW+g5Eftf9daZ5qvZ
  ```
- encrypted

  ```
  $ head ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----    
  Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
  DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,A95215C9E9FE00B8D73C58BE005DAD82

  ZAzLq/LbHSfOVkXtQz6M6U8yuAx2lIu9bH/k7ksgat92IDjZntRrT1XMpkYtjB+0
  ```

So you have to do one of the following:

1. If it's encrypted you can [try to remove the encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/112396/55075).
2. You're using wrong key. If you'd like to use different key, specify other file or edit your `~/.ssh/config` and specify different identity file (`IdentityFile`).
3. Run `ssh-add -l` to list all your identities (then compare with your local) and double check with Stash if you're using the right keys (they exists on Stash configuration).
4. If you know passphrase and you want to automate it, try the following workaround:

   ```
   PS="my_passphrase"
   install -vm700 <(echo "echo $PS") $PWD/my_pass
   DISPLAY= SSH_ASKPASS=$PWD/my_pass ssh-add - && rm -v my_pass
   ```

Troubleshooting:

1. Double check your SSH agent is running (`eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`).
2. Re-run git via: `GIT_TRACE=1 git pull` or with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vv"` (Git 2.3.0+) to debug your command again.
3. You can try to bypass asking for the passphrase (which will redirect it into `true`), but I don't think it'll help. If it asks for it, there is a reason for that and it's basically required.

   ```
   DISPLAY= SSH_ASKPASS=/bin/true ssh-add
   ```

Answer (score 4):

The `ssh-add` program starts an *agent* which can hold (and provide) your passphrase. The way to use it remotely is in a *parent* of your interactive shell (so that the agent does not stop).

Here are a few related questions:

- [Running ssh-agent from a shell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/547923/running-ssh-agent-from-a-shell-script)
- [Start ssh-agent on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880024/start-ssh-agent-on-login)
- [Using ssh-agent with ssh](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh)

Now... connecting *remotely*, as a rule your command does not log in as such, so it does not start `ssh-add`.  You could work around this, by executing a script which

- starts `ssh-agent`
- starts `ssh-add`
- adds your key
- runs the command that you want.

The weak point is the second step: you would *still* get prompted for the passphrase, unless you [weaken your security by using a key that has no passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112396/how-do-i-remove-the-passphrase-for-the-ssh-key-without-having-to-create-a-new-ke).  Some people do this, most people advise against.

Comment: `ssh-add` does not start the agent. It connects to an already-running agent.

Comment: Thanks - I'm used to doing these in separate scripts, and overlooked the missing part.

Answer (score 4):

To get asked for a passphrase only once when SSH tries to use a key for the first time add this at the beginning of your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

If you're still being asked more than once then check if you're not running multiple agents at once. To run only one `ssh-agent` per session add something like this to your RC file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```sh
if [ -S ~/.ssh/socket ]; then
    eval $(ssh-agent)
    ln -sf "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ~/.ssh/socket
fi
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/socket
```

Comment: Simply the AddKeysToAgent was enough

Comment: It usually is, at least in systems that already take care of spawning only one SSH agent, but I had to added that bit for folks with less automated distributions (see: Arch) who accidentally run more than one agent at the same time. I'll put the SSH config bit first.

Answer (score 3):

**You will still get password prompt to decrypt private key even if it is loaded into `ssh-agent`** until the corresponding SSH public key is added into remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

To reproduce:

```bash
# We are about to ssh to localhost, therefore, unauthorized everyone.
$ rm ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

$ eval $(ssh-agent)
# Agent pid 9290

$ ssh-add
# Enter passphrase for /home/uvsmtid/.ssh/id_rsa: 
# Identity added: /home/uvsmtid/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/uvsmtid/.ssh/id_rsa)

$ ssh localhost
# Enter passphrase for key '/home/uvsmtid/.ssh/id_rsa':
# uvsmtid@localhost's password:
  # NOTE: See password prompt for private key
  #       (and only then prompt for remote login).
  #       Why? Isn't the private key is already loaded by `ssh-add`?

$ ssh-copy-id localhost
$ ssh localhost
  # NOTE: No password for private key anymore.
  #       The key is served by `ssh-agent`.
```

Confusing enough. Remote SSH login password would be enough in this case.

I can speculate that this prevents adding your public key (which is paired with encrypted private key) without knowing encryption password for corresponding private key. It is one-time-per-remote-login procedure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps work for me on mac.

```
$ ssh-keygen -p
# Start the SSH key creation process
> Enter file in which the key is (/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa): [Hit enter]
> Key has comment '/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa'
> Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type new passphrase]
> Enter same passphrase again: [One more time for luck]
> Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Details link is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases)